# Event of ImageView when click

Tags: android

I have 1 ImageView close at B adapter, when I click close ImageView is 1 item is deleted from ArrayList. I also have 1 toggle button at A adapter, this toggle button is add and remove item from ArrayList. Now, I want when I click close ImageView is toggle button at index in A adapter will be enable is false. So, How can do this ?

Some image figure:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post your Adapter code or an image that describe this behavior?

Comment: I added some image above

Answer (score 2):

add listener in A adapter and B adapter, just like add onItemClickListener in RecyclerView. And your code will like this:

```
BAdapter.setOnImageViewClickListener { position ->
        AAdapter.setToggleButtonEnable(position, false)
}
```

Comment: at imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
         @Override public void onClick(View v) {}
}

How can I get position in adapter ?

Comment: if you write `setOnClickListenre` in `onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder holder, int position)`, the position is in function signature.

Comment: in terms of difference between position getAdapterPosition(), and getLayoutPosition() in RecyclerView. you can refer ths article:https://medium.com/@noureldeen.abouelkassem/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1